# How to load CSS for different URL in spring MVC app

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem loading css for different URL.

This is my current structure:

```
-webapp
  |--resources
       |---css
            |---generalize.css
       |---js
       |---images
  |--WEB-INF
       |---views
           |---login
           |---dashboard
```

This is my spring configuration to look for the resources:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And in the jsp page, I try to load it as:

```
<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/generalize.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I have an url like localhost:8888/myapp/login or localhost:8888/myapp/dashboard, the css will apply fine. But when I try to map the dashboard page with the url localhost:8888/myapp/user/dashboard, the page loses its css style. Would anyone help to explain how would be the correct way to load the css (or using the resources)?

I have tried to prepend the contextPath as below but it does not work as well.

```
<link href="<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/generalize.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use context relative path by appending `/` in the beginning.

```
<c:url value="/resources/css/generalize.css" />
```

You don't need to append context path in the beginning.